# Read document cookies in Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, dom, cookies

I want to read the cookies out of the DOM document object. 
I tried the following:

Controller:

```
init : function(component, event, helper) {
     console.log(document.cookie); // returns nothing
}
```

Renderer:

```
afterRender : function(component, helper) {
    console.log(document.cookie); // returns nothing
}
```

I want to read the Salesforce session id out of the cookies. 
I also tried to get the session id via apex:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static string requestSession() {
    return UserInfo.getSessionId();
}
```

But I can not use the returned id for REST API calls. But the sid in the cookies works for REST API.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to read the SecureDocument.cookie attribute [Locker Service document.cookie support](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/154415/locker-service-document-cookie-support)

But for your use case Salesforce recommends using Named Credentials to authenticate to Salesforce.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/apex_api_calls.htm